# How to change in game soundtrack?

Tags: starcraft-2

When you play Zerg there is a specific soundtrack that starts in game. Same for Terran and Protoss.

Is there a way to listen to the Terran soundtrack playing as Zerg for example?

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways I see:

1. disable in-game music (in options or by pressing `crtl+m`) and listen for external player
2. modify MPQ files and replace Zerg music with whatever you want. Please, remember that modifications of game files is a call for banhammer.